# How to make gradient on the screen of my game

Tags: java, processing

This is my simple game and I need to make my background have a gradient. The blue needs to be lighter on the bottom and darker blue on the top. I need the green grass to still be in the picture. I could only make it that it has black on the top. Can someone help me with this. I am using processing

```java
int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;

void setup() {
    size(640, 480);
    changeinbackground();
}

void draw() {
    changeinbackground();

    drawsun();
    noStroke();
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(0);
}

void drawsun() {
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    ellipse(20, 30, 120, 120);
}

void changeinbackground() {
    {
        fill(0, 255, 0); // colour selected for the grass on the bottom
        stroke(20, 255, 0); //green outline
        rect(0, 430, 650, 55); // grass on the bottom
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<400; i +=10 ){
        fill(r,g,i);
        noStroke();
        rect(0,i,640,40);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]"

Comment: Can you please tell us if this issue is solved or still remaining?